# API calls issue with an HTTPS API with Swagger UI behind ingress-nginx on Azure AKS

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I'm exposing an HTTPS service API gateway with Swagger UI hosted on Azure AKS Cluster with ingress-nginx controller https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/

Exposing the path my-domain.com/swagger works fine but when I try to make API calls( POST, GET, ...) I get a 404 error.

My ingress configuration configuration is the following:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: api-gateway-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/from-to-www-redirect: "true"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod #letsencrypt-staging
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'true'
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - my-domain.com
      secretName: tp-api-gateway-wildcard # get it from certificate.yaml
  rules:
    - host: my-domain.com
      http:
        paths: 
          - path: /swagger
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: api-gateway
                port:
                  number: 80
  ingressClassName: nginx
```

Anyone has an idea how can I successfully make the API calls ?
Thank you

Comment: Could you provide ingress logs? Where would you like to make your API calls to? Can I ask you how you tested that domain/path works?

Answer (score 1):

Managed to make API calls because I exposed only the subpath `/swagger` where I could access only `my-domain.com/swagger` and not other paths.

Changed configuration such as :

```
...
rules:
    - host: my-domain.com
      http:
        paths: 
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
...
```